# Button "Run job" locked - can't run any job

Tags: talend

I have a problem with my Talend Open Studio since this morning.
Yesterday, all were working fine and this morning, I launched TOS and I cannot rur any of my jobs. (I did not touch anything ... strange)

Here an example :
[image]

- I open a job
- In red : "No job to run" ...
- In blue : the button is grey ...

It is as if my Workspace was in read only mode !
None of my job can be ran. And even if I create a new job, I can't run it too ...

I restarted Talend, I restarted my computer and download again TOS and affect my workspace to it ... still not working. I just tried to create a new workspace and create a new job and it does not work.

This button does not change anything. [image] It does nothing.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Damien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 3h, I found the solution !

In fact when I said that I created a new workspace I were wrong, I created a new "Local_Project" IN my current workspace.. And it never worked because it seems to be my whole workspace which went wrong when I close Talend yesterday.

My solution is :

- Export all my jobs, contexts, metadata, routines ... from my current worksapce
- Create a new "workspace" folder
- Link Talend whith this new empty workspace
- Create a new "Local_Project" in the new workspace
- Import all the jobs

I can work again !

The good question is what happened yesterday ... No idea !

Hope it will help.

Damien.